# Requesting the Write External Storage Permission

Tags: java, android

I have a button that when pressed, asks once, but if it says no, it does not ask me again

How can I indicate that if he says no, he can ask again?

**Check Permission**

```
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){

            if (checkPermission()){
                // Code for above or equal 23 API Oriented Device
                // Your Permission granted already .Do next code
            } else {
                requestPermission(); // Code for permission
            }
        }
        else{
            // Code for Below 23 API Oriented Device
            // Do next code
        }
```

**My Code Permission - Main.java**

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private void requestPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Main.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "NECESITAMOS QUE NOS CONCEDAS LOS PERMISOS DE ALMACENAMIENTO PARA GUARDAR NOTICIAS O RADIOS COMO FAVORITOS.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.e("value", "Permiso otorgado, ahora puedes usar la unidad local.");
            } else {
                Log.e("value", "Permiso denegado, no puede usar la unidad local.");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this:**
Myclass for runtime permissions:

```
public class RequestPermissionHandler {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private RequestPermissionListener mRequestPermissionListener;
    private int mRequestCode;

public void requestPermission(Activity activity, @NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode,
        RequestPermissionListener listener) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mRequestCode = requestCode;
    mRequestPermissionListener = listener;

    if (!needRequestRuntimePermissions()) {
        mRequestPermissionListener.onSuccess();
        return;
    }
    requestUnGrantedPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
}

private boolean needRequestRuntimePermissions() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
}

private void requestUnGrantedPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
    String[] unGrantedPermissions = findUnGrantedPermissions(permissions);
    if (unGrantedPermissions.length == 0) {
        mRequestPermissionListener.onSuccess();
        return;
    }
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, unGrantedPermissions, requestCode);
}

private boolean isPermissionGranted(String permission) {
    return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, permission)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private String[] findUnGrantedPermissions(String[] permissions) {
    List<String> unGrantedPermissionList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        if (!isPermissionGranted(permission)) {
            unGrantedPermissionList.add(permission);
        }
    }
    return unGrantedPermissionList.toArray(new String[0]);
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == mRequestCode) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0) {
            for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
                if (grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mRequestPermissionListener.onFailed();
                    return;
                }
            }
            mRequestPermissionListener.onSuccess();
        } else {
            mRequestPermissionListener.onFailed();
        }
    }
}

public interface RequestPermissionListener {
    void onSuccess();

    void onFailed();
}
```

}

Use in `Activity` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RequestPermissionHandler mRequestPermissionHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRequestPermissionHandler = new RequestPermissionHandler();

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                handleButtonClicked();
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleButtonClicked(){
        mRequestPermissionHandler.requestPermission(this, new String[] {
                Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        }, 123, new RequestPermissionHandler.RequestPermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "request permission success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "request permission failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
            @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        mRequestPermissionHandler.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                grantResults);
    }
}
```

**Gif image link for code behaviour.**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha5LT.gif

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I was looking for. =)

Answer (score 1):

Don't base your call to `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` on the result of `ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()`.  The `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` method is used to determine whether or not to present something on screen to justify why you need the permission (in case the user rejected the request), not whether you should request it.  If it returns `false`, the user ask asked to not be asked again and you should not try to justify the permission.

You may find this talk helpful: https://youtu.be/WGz-alwVh8A